# Selection of items in listview in wpf (MVVM)

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm

I have two listviews and two buttons(add and remove). I can select an item from one list view to another listview. I have achieved the movement of items from one list to another.But I want the moved item to be selected in the other listview as well. If i select multiple items and move it then I want the multiple items to be selected in the moved listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you added the items to the second `ListBox`, and them to the second `ListBox`'s `SelectedItems` property too. You can call the `Clear()` method of the `SelectedItems` property before adding items to it so that only the new items will be selected.

Example:

```
list2.SelectedItems.Clear();

foreach (var item in list1.SelectedItems.OfType<object>().ToArray())
{
     list1.Items.Remove(item);
     list2.Items.Add(item);
     list2.SelectedItems.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: @Virus while I did something like this with ListView on ListBox, I think the concept is right. Perhaps you have a binding issue to the SelectedItems?

Comment: yes probably! First thing is it shows up only 'SelectedItem' property and not 'SelectedItems'. Even if I bind a single item to the list view, it doesnt reflect in the listview.

Comment: @Virus: If the `ListView` doesn't have focus, the selected items are gray instead of blue which will be hard to see. Also, in order to have more than one item selected, you must set the `ListBox.SelectionMode` property to `Extended` (or `Multiple` if you only want to be able to select uninterrupted ranges of items, not recommended) and use the [`SelectedItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selecteditems.aspx) (not `SelectedItem`) property to specify which items are selected.

Comment: Can you please provide a very simple example. I am using listview and not listbox.

Comment: @Virus: Sure. I've updated the answer. If you're binding the `ListView.ItemsSource` to a collection then replace `list1.Items` and/or `list2.Items` with the bound collection.